# Scala Queue and NoSuchElementException

Tags: scala, exception, queue

I am getting an infrequent NoSuchElementException error when operating over my Scala 2.9.2 Queue.  I don't understand the exception becase the Queue has elements in it.  I've tried switching over to a SynchronizedQueue, thinking it was a concurrency issue (my queue is written and read to from different threads) but that didn't solve it.

The reduced code looks like this:

```
val window = new scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Packet]
...
(thread 1)
window += packet
...
(thread 2)
window.dequeueAll(someFunction)
println(window.size)
window.foreach(println(_))
```

Which results in

```
32
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at scala.collection.mutable.LinkedListLike$class.head(LinkedListLike.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList.head(LinkedList.scala:78)
    at scala.collection.mutable.MutableList.head(MutableList.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.MutableList.foreach(MutableList.scala:30)
```

The docs for LinkedListLike.head() say

```
 Exceptions thrown
 `NoSuchElementException`
 if the linked list is empty.
```

but how can this exception be thrown if the Queue is not empty?

Comment: Don't use mutable shared data

Comment: How are you sure it's not empty?

Comment: Or, if you're bent on sharing a mutable queue, use a [`SynchronizedQueue`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.SynchronizedQueue). Easier than manual synchronization.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  Could you give a small example of a program that runs into your problem?  The one you provided doesn't seem to work for me (using Int instead of Packet, and _ => true as someFunction)

Answer (score 0):

You should have `window` (mutable data structure) accessed from only a single thread. Other threads should send messages to that one.

There is [Akka](http://akka.io/) that allows relatively easy concurrent programming.

```
class MySource(windowHolderRef:ActorRef) {
  def receive = {
    case MyEvent(packet:Packet) =>
      windowHolderRef ! packet
  }
}

case object CheckMessages

class WindowHolder {
  private val window = new scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Packet]
  def receive = {
    case packet:Packet =>
      window += packet
    case CheckMessages =>
      window.dequeueAll(someFunction)
      println(window.size)
      window.foreach(println(_))
  }
}
```

To check messages periodically you can [schedule](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/scheduler.html) periodic messages.

```
  // context.schedule(1 second, 1 second, CheckMessages)
```